# Is the differentiation operator normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

In the space of polynomials (degree not higher than n) , the scalar product is given by the formula: 
$$(f,g)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx$$

is the differentiation operator normal?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 4):

This is never true for $n\geq 1$:

Let $D$ be the differential operator and $D^*$ it's adjoint.
Then
$$\langle x,D^*(1)\rangle =\langle D(x),1\rangle=\langle 1,1\rangle=1$$
so $D^*(1)\neq 0$ and hence

$$\langle DD^*(1),1\rangle=\langle D^*(1),D^*(1)\rangle=\|D^*(1)\|^2\neq 0$$
which then implies $DD^*(1)\neq 0$.

But $D^*D(1)=D^*(0)=0$, so $D^*D\neq DD^*$.